# Mongoose: How to add multiple plugins

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In Mongoose, I've never actually seen an example of setting multiple Mongoose plugins on a schema.
All I ever see is

```
schema.plugin(mongooseSearchPlugin);
```

How does one go about adding another plugin to that?  e.g. mongoosePaginatePlugin?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately mongoose doesn't support initializing multiple plugins at once. So the only option is to call `schema.plugin(...)` multiple times.

You can can call the function multiple times to initialize all your plugins like this:

```
schema.plugin(mongooseSearchPlugin);
schema.plugin(mongoosePaginatePlugin);
```

Alternatively, if you store your functions in an iterable (something like an array) you can just iterate over each item and initialize it that way. Something like this:

```
const myPlugins = [ mongooseSearchPlugin, mongoosePaginatePlugin ];

myPlugins.forEach(plugin => schema.plugin(plugin));

// Or you can you block style
myPlugins.forEach((plugin) => {
    schema.plugin(plugin);
});
```

Depending on how many plugins you're using this might make your code shorter. Ultimately it's a styling choice.

Hope this explanation helped.

Answer (score 2):

Simply call `schema.plugin` multiple times